# Phonegap and Jquery mobile - Exit app with an alert

Tags: jquery, cordova

i want to exit my app with an alert of Yes or No. I currently have a script that exits the app when you are on the index side of the app.

```
<script language="javascript">

document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e){
    if($.mobile.activePage.is('#index')){
        /* 
         Event preventDefault/stopPropagation not required as adding backbutton
          listener itself override the default behaviour. Refer below PhoneGap link.
        */
        //e.preventDefault();
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
    else {
        navigator.app.backHistory()
    }
}, false);

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the dialogs plugin with the confirm

install using the cordova CLI it if you don't have it yet:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs
```

if you use phonegap build put this on your config.xml instead:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" version="0.2.10" />
```

your code

```
<script language="javascript">

document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e){
    if($.mobile.activePage.is('#index')){
        /* 
         Event preventDefault/stopPropagation not required as adding backbutton
          listener itself override the default behaviour. Refer below PhoneGap link.
        */
        //e.preventDefault();

        navigator.notification.confirm(
            "Do you want to exit the app?",
            function (button) {
              if (button==2) {
                navigator.app.exitApp();
              }
            }
            ,
            "EXIT",
            ["Cancel","OK"]
        );
    }
    else {
        navigator.app.backHistory()
    }
}, false);

</script>
```

Comment: please where do i place "cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs". in the config.xml or in a javascript tag?

Comment: are you using cordova or phonegap build? if you use cordova, then you have to use the CLI, from terminal or CMD, on your project folder, you write "cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs"

Comment: i'm using phonegap build

Comment: jcesarmobile - the event is fired before the app closes? Is that approved by the developer guidelines?

Comment: I've edited the answer to add how to use dialogs on phonegap build. The alert will be shown when you press the back button on the index, and then the app will close if you press OK button